# Linq Where() not working bitwise operators

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, mariadb

I'm trying to build an asp.net api using Entity Framework MySql

```
(IQueryable).where(b=>(((fliter ^ b.BlogStatus) & mask) == 0));
```

error=`System.InvalidOperationException: Unsupported Binary operator type specified.`

But EOR(^) doesn't work
I couldn't find a solution for this so I decided not to use "EOR"

```
(IQueryable).where(b=>(((fliter  | b.BlogStatus) & ~(fliter  & b.BlogStatus)) & mask) == 0);
// x^y == (x|y) & ~(x&y)
```

error=`MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT (0 & 'b'.'BlogStatus')) & 7) = 0`

But NOT(~) doesn't work
I couldn't find a solution for this so I decided not to use "NOT"

```
(IQueryable).where(b=>(((fliter | b.BlogStatus) & (2147483647-(fliter & b.BlogStatus))&mask)) == 0);
// ~x == 2147483647-x
```

Surprisingly it works but only locally.

- Could it be because mariaDb is on the server?
- How can I get this to work without doing nonsense?
- Why don't bitwise operators work?

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Maybe try it not as a single line lambda, but an anonymous function with { and } instead? This is because LINQ providers usually turn LINQ into an Expression tree and then translate that to the underlying SQL to execute. However, C# does not turn anonymous functions with a body into expression trees (but rather a method call expression). From your error I think you've hit an unsupported translation situation. Burying the offending operator(s) inside {} might help the translator out if its problem, I think. Hope that helps!

Comment: It says unsupported type -- what are the types of `fliter`, `b.BlogStatus`, `mask`

Comment: @Hogan fliter and BlogStatus are int

Comment: @Atduyar -- what type is mask?

Comment: @Hogan it's also int